# Including local frameworks through CocoaPods?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

We have an iOS project that uses CocoaPods. However, for legal reasons some of the frameworks we use cannot be distributed that way and need to be committed directly and manually added to the "Link Binaries With Libraries" on the target.

We disable warnings for all pods using `inhibit_all_warnings!`. The local frameworks generate a lot of warnings that cannot be disabled unless they go through pods.

Is it possible to use the Podfile to include local frameworks?

P.S. The frameworks are precompiled so they do not contain the original source to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it by creating a private pod and add the path to your framework in the local podspec file

May be this [blog post](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-a-third-party-framework-in-a-private-cocoapod) can help you in how to setup a private pod